# passing a referrer link using a m3u playlist file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vlc, mp3, lua

I can pass a referrer link in VLC using a Lua file by typing in **vlc ipchannel.lua**  (see example of Lua file below).  But how can I pass a referrer link using an m3u playlist file?

**Example of working referrer link using a Lua file**
Taken from Roy Shilkrot example. (the others didn't work for me) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50108330/how-to-set-http-user-agent-for-vlc

```
#EXTVLCOPT:http-user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.25 Safari/537.36
#EXTVLCOPT:http-referrer=https://fromserver.ip.tv/channel/
https://peer2.fakeip.tv/iptv/myStream/playlist.m3u8?wmsAuthSign=c2VydmVyX3RpbWU9MTIvNC8yMDE5IDQ6MTU6NTEgUE0maGFzaF92YWx1ZT1uWE05cFRmYWNweTNFOUFIVHZYd3JnPT0mdmFsaW
```

I tried this as m3u playlist file (trying to pass a referrer link to it but it doesn't work)

```
#EXTM3U x-tvg-url="http://epg.streamstv.me/epg/guide-canada.xml.gz"
#EXTVLCOPT:http-user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.25 Safari/537.36
#EXTVLCOPT:http-referrer=https://fromserver.ip.tv/channel/
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="" tvg-language="English" tvg-logo="https://i.imgur.com/k9M5ydW.png" group-title="",Test TV
https://peer2.fakeip.tv/iptv/myStream/playlist.m3u8?wmsAuthSign=c2VydmVyX3RpbWU9MTIvNC8yMDE5IDQ6MTU6NTEgUE0maGFzaF92YWx1ZT1uWE05cFRmYWNweTNFOUFIVHZYd3JnPT0mdmFsaWRtaW
```

PS:  I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 64bit Linux